# Ruby can't find psych.so despite it existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm, yaml

After installing Rails with rvm, I was faced with the following error:

```
/afs/andrew.cmu.edu/usr11/kvudata/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in '<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

So to get a little more information, I went irb and tried to require 'psych':

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'psych'
LoadError: libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -/afs/andrew.cmu.edu/usr11/kvudata/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
```

But when I navigate to the specified location where it's trying to find `psych.so`, it exists!

I have tried uninstalling ruby and reinstalling as well as uninstalling, compiling libyaml from source, and then reinstalling ruby, but to no avail, the error doesn't go away.

Comment: I am guessing: but if the file exists, does it have the correct permissions?

Comment: Tried installing libyaml again?

Comment: @TarynEast the file has rwx permissions for me and r-x permissions for group/everyone else so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: maybe the file was build for different platform, most of systems supports dual architectures, currently most popular is default 64bit with support for 32bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't feel like a "real" solution, but I was able to get things working.

In my case, libyaml is installed in `/usr/local/lib`. Adding that path to my environment variables did the trick (inspired by [Shared Libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Shared-Libraries.html)). I added the following to my .bash_profile

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For other visitors who - like me - are trying to make this work with capistrano, adding this to my deploy.rb worked:

```
set :default_environment, {'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' => '/usr/local/lib'}
```

I look forward to more informed suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I downloaded and compiled libyaml myself into ~/lib and added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib` to my .bash_profile